# Creating a textual copy of the apl language bar

Tags: unicode, copy, symbols, apl, dyalog

I would like to embed a picture of the Dyalog APL language bar into text and PowerPoint material. How can I do that? It would be nice to be able to select and paste it.

Answer (score 1):

Embed a picture - you mean this?

[image]

I would:

- ALT-CTRL-PrtScn to get the bitmap image of the window in focus, then
- Paste into MS-Paint, then crop off all but the wanted part, as I did here.
- Alternately, some products, notably Word and Outlook, have the ability to crop the picture in-situ once you've pasted it.
- Possibly PowerPoint has this feature as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://abrudz.github.io/lb/apl) has a text-based language bar you can select, copy and paste the characters from. Just note that it includes two more characters (`∆⍙`) at the end, not found in Dyalog's IDEs.

These are the characters on Dyalog's language bars:

```
← +-×÷*⍟⌹○!? |⌈⌊⊥⊤⊣⊢ =≠≤<>≥≡≢ ∨∧⍲⍱ ↑↓⊂⊃⊆⌷⍋⍒ ⍳⍸∊⍷∪∩~ /\⌿⍀ ,⍪⍴⌽⊖⍉ ¨⍨⍣.∘⍤⍥@ ⍞⎕⍠⌸⌺⌶⍎⍕ ⋄⍝→⍵⍺∇& ¯⍬
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get the actual language bar content. Just note that the solution is fundamentally fragile: Dyalog might change the way the language bar is configured, and the I-beams may be removed or changed. In particular, `4070⌶` is undocumented and thus unsupported, and might change or disappear without notice.

```
 file←(739⌶0),'\elements.reg' ⍝ file name in temporary directory
 {}⎕CMD'reg export "',(⊃4070⌶0),'\LanguageBar\Elements" "',file,'" /y' ⍝ export registry key
 ⊃¨0⎕JSON¨'"av char"=(.*)'⎕S'\1'⊃⎕NGET file ⍝ extract data stings and evaluate escapes
```

On my machine, this results in:

```
← +-×÷*⍟⌹○!? |⌈⌊⊥⊤⊣⊢ =≠≤<>≥≡≢ ∨∧⍲⍱ ↑↓⊂⊃⊆⌷⍋⍒ ⍳⍸∊⍷∪∩~ /\⌿⍀ ,⍪⍴⌽⊖⍉ ¨⍨⍣.∘⍤⍥@ ⍞⎕⍠⌸⌺⌶⍎⍕ ⋄⍝→⍵⍺∇& ¯⍬
```